# Як перекладати словосполучення на кшталт «characteristic time»

Tags: переклад, словосполучення

Мені завжди незрозуміло як перекладати словосполучення на кшталт «characteristic time»,  це має бути «характеристичний час» чи «часова характеристика»? Чим керуватись під час перекладу таких словосполучень?

Приклад:

> You can express the transients in terms of exponentials written as
>   $e^{−t/t_0}$ (perhaps times sinusoids); $t_0$ is the "**characteristic time**" of
>   this decaying exponential.

---

> Ти можеш виразити тимчасові через показникові функції записані як 
>   $e^{−t/t_0}$ (можливо домножені на синусоїди); $t_0$ - це
>   «**характеристичний час**»/«**часова характеристика**» цієї сгасної експоненти.

Comment: Буду вдячний за редагування назви і тегів, бо я просто не знаю як правильніше написати.

Comment: Якщо чесно, по-моєму, поза темою; бо радше про англійську мову, а не про українську. В англійській прикметник йде першим. Так, в окремих випадках можна міняти місцями (як _гігрометричний психрометр_ і _психрометричний гігрометр_) або навіть прийнято міняти ролями (в одній мові щось прийнято називати _<x>ий y_, а в інший — _<y>ий x_) — але це трапляється порівняно нечасто. Нижче у відповіді намагаюся пояснити, чому **і в данному конкретному випадку**, по-моєму, не варто міняти (а цей коментар про те, що **зазвичай** не міняють).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

«**Характеристичний час**».

«Часова характеристика» може звучати інтуїтивніше/знайоміше — але в тому-то й справа, що «часова характеристика» просто є побутовим словосполученням із широким спектром значень, а не відповідником терміну «[characteristic time](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_time)».

*Часова характеристика* взагазі-то не одна. Як є для різновидів військогої техніки поняття *[ТТХ — тактико-технічні характеристики](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8)*… Як *швидкісні характеристики* автомобільних двигунів (максимальна (номінальна) еффективна потужність, кутова швидкість колінчастого вала за максимальної потужності, максимальний крутний момент тощо)… Як є *габаритні характеристики* (довжина, ширина, висота тощо)… Як є силові, біомеханічні та інші характеристики… Так є й *часов**і** характеристик**и*** — наприклад, часові характеристики оперативної пам'яті комп'ютера (час повного доступу, час робочого циклу, RAS precharge тощо — на противагу надмірності, ціні та іншим *не часовим* характеристикам).

Тобто словосполучення «часова характеристика» зазвичай не позначає конкретну величину, а є узагальненою назвою для широкого набору різних величин, що характеризують час чогось. Звісно, не виключена можливість співпадіння (що тип самим словосполученням позначають і конкретную величину; наприклад, як «[ягода](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)» є одночасно побутовим словом і ботанічним терміном із зовсім іншим значенням) або звуження значення за традицією (як під словосполученням «тернарний оператор» часто розуміють [конкретний тернарний оператор](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)) — але в першому наближенні виглядає так, що «часова характеристики» («часові характеристики») є просто побутовим словосполученням, а як відповідник для терміну «characteristic time» слід використовувати «характеристичний час» (хай навіть значення терміну «характеристичний час» і різнитиметься в різних науках).